# Laptop won't boot from HDD, only USB, even though the HDD seems to be fine

Tags: linux, hard-drive, boot, laptop, usb

I have a Toshiba Satellite, about 5 years old that was struggling with Windows 10 so I installed KUbuntu on it a few months ago to try out Linux and it was working fine.

The other day it stopped booting, just sitting on the Toshiba splash screen. No beeps, no messages, nothing. All I can do is get into the BIOS with F2.

So I tried a bunch of things suggested online, like powercycling it, turning off Secure Boot, changing the boot order etc.

Eventually I tried making a bootable usb of Linux Mint and booting from that. It worked, so I installed it onto the computer permanently, wiping the old installation completely, thinking the issue was maybe some kind of corruption with the old OS. The computer worked well for about half a day. I restarted it a few times and everything, it was working fine and 100% running off the HDD.

Then this morning it's back to being stuck at the Toshiba screen.

I can still boot off the USB, but I'm looking for a permanent solution. The HDD seems to be fine at first glance (I didn't run any diagnostics, that may be the next step), but the machine just will not boot from it. If I leave the HDD as the first boot option, and insert a bootable USB, it will still boot from USB, so it just skips the HDD like it's not there. And yet if I boot from USB I can see the hard drive and all the stuff on it without issue.

Any help is much appreciated, as well as suggestions on what are good Linux diagnostic tools to use for this, I'm fairly new to the Linux world.

Answer (score 0):

Hello Brother first of all you should reset bios all settings on default then you change hard drive mode (ATA to AHCI) or (AHCI to ATA). try it.

Comment: Thank you. I believe that already happened when I powercycled it, because I had to set the system time again afterwards. I can try doing it again though.